# Load my regsitartion page in CMS page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, magento-2.1.8, registration

My registration page is coming from path:

> /app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

I am trying to load that in a CMS page. Not sure how to do that. Tried many ways but no luck.
including `{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="custom-create"  template="Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml"}}`

How to include that in CMS page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Try to below code :

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register"  template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml"}}
```

Comment: @H_Parekh, how your answer was different than the answer of Amit Bera?

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="custom-create"  template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml"}}
```

Comment: how your answer was different than the answer of Amit Bera?

Comment: I think you have missed the added time. All 3 added almost same time, 1st Parekh but with a minor mistake (that was edited later), 2nd me, 3rd Amit

Answer (score 1):

template path is wrong

**It should be**

```
template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml
```

**from**

```
template="Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml"
```